# collapse some and keep some nav links visible - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to collapse some nav links and keep others visible when the browser width decreses.
I.e. From the following code, i'd like to collapse only the login, about and contact, and leave the cart visible to the left of the collapsed (icon bar). Any idea how i can achieve that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="~/">Nav</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/login.cshtml"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Fix your `<a>` tags on `about` and `contact`, they're missing the closing `</a>` on each.

Comment: If the content you don't want to collapse is inside the navbar-collapse, then it's going to collapse. Options repeat and hide/show with responsive utility classes OR create another navbar-right or left outside of the collapse or use the other helper classes to add a couple links (just like the brand is outside).